# Wildcarded favorite tags don't show up in the favorite tags filter

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching, new-nav

In the new navigation, the 'new' tab, when you choose the 'favorite tags' filter, it brings up my non-wildcarded favorite tags, but doesn't bring up my wildcarded ones.

[image: Tags Brought Up]

[image: My Favorite Tags]

Answer (score -1):

Acknowledged.

We are aware of it -- we are not supporting that for now, though.